# Does Accelerated magic item crafting increase the daily cap?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

Magic Creation rules

> The creator also needs a fairly quiet, comfortable, and well-lit place in which to work. Any place suitable for preparing spells is suitable for making items. **Creating an item requires 8 hours of work per 1,000 gp** in the item's base price (or fraction thereof), with a minimum of at least 8 hours. Potions and scrolls are an exception to this rule; they can take as little as 2 hours to create (if their base price is 250 gp or less). Scrolls and potions whose base price is more than 250 gp, but less than 1,000 gp, take 8 hours to create, just like any other magic item. The character must spend the gold at the beginning of the construction process. Regardless of the time needed for construction, a caster can create no more than one magic item per day. **This process can be accelerated to 4 hours of work per 1,000 gp** in the item's base price (or fraction thereof) by increasing the DC to create the item by 5.
>
> **The caster can work for up to 8 hours each day.** He cannot rush the process by working longer each day, but the days need not be consecutive, and the caster can use the rest of his time as he sees fit. If the caster is out adventuring, he can devote 4 hours each day to item creation, although he nets only 2 hours' worth of work. This time is not spent in one continuous period, but rather during lunch, morning preparation, and during watches at night. If time is dedicated to creation, it must be spent in uninterrupted 4-hour blocks. This work is generally done in a controlled environment, where distractions are at a minimum, such as a laboratory or shrine. Work that is performed in a distracting or dangerous environment nets only half the amount of progress (just as with the adventuring caster).

And the Feat

> Craft Wondrous Item (Item Creation)
>
> You can create wondrous items, a type of magic item.
>
> Prerequisite: Caster level 3rd.
>
> Benefit: You can create a wide variety of magic wondrous items. **Crafting a wondrous item takes 1 day for each 1,000 gp in its price.** To create a wondrous item, you must use up raw materials costing half of its base price. See the magic item creation rules in Magic Items for more information.
>
> You can also mend a broken wondrous item if it is one that you could make. Doing so costs half the raw materials and half the time it would take to craft that item.

1. Creating an item requires 8 hours of work per 1,000 gp
2. This process can be accelerated to 4 hours of work per 1,000 gp
3. You can work for up to 8 hours each day.
4. Crafting takes 1 day for each 1,000gp in its price.

Does this mean that I can increase the DC by 5 to Craft 2,000 gp worth in a day or am I still limited to the mechanics of the feats for crafting that don't allow for more than 1,000gp/day?

If so, is there any official backing to that?

Answer (score 6):

### 2000gp/day

The feat only gives a very short description of the item creation rules, and then refers the reader to the actual rules:

> **Benefit:** You can create a wide variety of magic wondrous items. Crafting a wondrous item takes 1 day for each 1,000 gp in its price. To create a wondrous item, you must use up raw materials costing half of its base price. **See the magic item creation rules in Magic Items for more information.**

The magic item creation rules are authorative and supersede the feat description. The "1 day per 1000 gp" rule is merely a convenient combination of the "8 hours per day", and "1 hour per 1000 gp" rules for the sake of brevity. Since the magic item creation rules state that accelerated crafting reduces the time spent to 4 hours per 1000 gp, but does not touch on the 8 hour daily limit, there is no reason to assume that the daily crafting time limit is suddenly reduced to 4 hours.

Answer (score -1):

**Rules as Written: No**.

Increasing the DC to create items accelerated will not reduce the total time it will take to craft an item.
If it would take 10 days, it will still take 10 days.

If the item costs 2000 gp (example: *ring of deflection +1*), you could make one ring every 2 days, or 16 hours of downtime work (see **Ultimate Campaign**). But with accelerated crafting, you can now craft the same ring in 8 hours of downtime, on two separate days, with another 8 free hours, which cannot be used to craft the same magic item.

**Rules as Intended: Probably Yes**.

Why? Every example we can find about accelerated crafting seems to indicate that the total time is reduced, thus the daily cap is doubled.
Like:

> Example: Patrick's wizard decides to use his downtime to increase the armor bonus on his bracers of armor +1 to +3. The price difference between the two types of bracers is 8,000 gp, so Patrick's wizard must spend 8 days and 4,000 gp (half the 8,000 gp price difference) upgrading his bracers' magic. If he has fewer than 8 days before the next adventure, he'll need to finish his crafting while traveling or use accelerated crafting in town to speed up the process.

(source: **Ultimate Campaign**)

Comment: "A character can work on only one item at a time. If a character starts work on a new item, all materials used on the under-construction item are wasted."

Does this not apply?

Comment: Yes, it does. I will correct my answer.

Comment: I think this is an example of the specific beats general rule design. The feat lists the basic process of item creation while the Magic Item Creation rules offer another option for modifying that rule set.

Comment: The rules stated in the feat are merely a short summary of the full rules. Paizo can't, and honestly shouldn't be expected to, list the full rules for crafting in each item creation feat. They even refers you to the magic item creation rules for further details.